# Is it possible to set figure axis_type in bokeh to geographical (long/lat)?

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, geo

I'm creating an application using python bokeh that plots points on a map. I have lat/long points, and I want to lay my points over the cartodbpositron tile.

All the examples that I've seen use the basic x_axis_type = "mercator" with x_range and y_range being mercator as well. I don't want to convert my long/lat coordinates to mercator using a formula as I don't want to lose the accuracy I need. Is there a way to set the x_y_range_type to geographical or something of that sort where it sets lat/long?

```py
USA = x_range,y_range = ((-13884029,-7453304), (2698291,6455972))

p = figure(tools='pan, wheel_zoom', x_range=x_range, y_range=y_range,
           x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator")
tile_provider = get_provider(Vendors.CARTODBPOSITRON)
p.add_tile(tile_provider)
```

My longitude latitude points are in california, but when I run this code I'll get my points in the middle of the ocean since it's mercator values.

I appreciate any help to a solution.

Comment: Bokeh can plot glyphs over a Google Map using [gmap()](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.gmap.gmap) function, this way you can keep your latitude and longitude.

Comment: I tried bokeh with gmap() at first but found that the performance wasn't quite that good compared to what I'm finding with how smoothly it might work with just a tile, since gmap() does not allow box select zoom.