# How to use extra extra_x_ranges, extra_y_ranges with add_tile in bokeh

Tags: maps, bokeh, geo

I want to use long/lat (EPSG:4326) coordinates in a bokeh plot and have a map in the Background.
I tried with the tile provider maps as suggested in [bokeh: Mapping geo data](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/geo.html).
But the format is in web mercator coordinates (EPSG:3857) and I don't want to convert my coordinates.

The general question how to do this is unanswered in [Is it possible to set figure axis_type in bokeh to geographical (long/lat)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639219/is-it-possible-to-set-figure-axis-type-in-bokeh-to-geographical-long-lat)

My idea was to use extra axes:

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import Range1d, LinearAxis
from bokeh.tile_providers import CARTODBPOSITRON, get_provider

tile_provider = get_provider(CARTODBPOSITRON)

p = figure(x_range=(-180, 180), y_range=(-90, 90))  # EPSG:4326

# add extra axis
p.extra_x_ranges = {"EPSG:3857x": Range1d(start=-20026376.39, end=20026376.39)}
p.extra_y_ranges = {"EPSG:3857y": Range1d(start=-20048966.10, end=20048966.10)}

# place extra axis
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(x_range_name="EPSG:3857x"), 'above')
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="EPSG:3857y"), 'right')

p.add_tile(tile_provider, x_range_name="EPSG:3857x", y_range_name="EPSG:3857y")

show(p)
```

But the map is not visible.

Is there a way to use extra axis for a tile_provider?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just asking about displaying lat/lng visually on the axes, then all you have to do is set the axis type to `"mercator"`

```py
p = figure(x_range=(-2000000, 6000000), y_range=(-1000000, 7000000),
           x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator")
```

This is demonstrated on the documentation page you linked.

If you are asking about using data that is in lan/lng coordinates to plot on a tile plot, then you will need to convert it to Web Mercator first. The underlying coordinate system for tiles is always Web Mercator.

If you are asking about something else, then your question is not clear (please update to clarify).

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply. Here I am trying to bring the tile_provider on extra axis, so a conversion is not necessary and lat/long can be used in ranges of -90 to 90 and -180 to 180.

Comment: Looking at the code, I don't actually think tile renderers properly recognize extra-ranges at this time. No one has asked about it in ten years so most likely just an oversight. You can file a [github issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues). I thikn the only option is to make the default ranges web mercator, and use the extra ranges for the lat/lng.